# Is it possible to pass parameters to a WebAssembly start function when the module is being loaded/instantiated?

Tags: webassembly

As per title, is it possible to pass parameters to a WebAssembly "start" function?

https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/modules.html#syntax-start

According to the docs linked above:
*The start function is intended for initializing the state of a module. The module and its exports are not accessible externally before this initialization has completed.*

Though it is not specified if this function is allowed to take any input parameters and I cannot seem to find anything related to this specific issue.

My understanding of this is that the start function is run regardless of what the module will do afterwards and is some sort of entry point that is executed upon loading the module before future usage of the exported functions which also allows WebAssembly to run independently form other languages by having a "main" function.

I tried compiling a handwritten module (wat2wasm) which set input values to the start function and it didn't return any errors.
My doubt still lies in the fact that I cannot seem to find any way in which I can set those parameters in, say, Javascript. Please mind that my JS knowledge is limited and I have used WASM as standalone VM-like bytecode only.